# How to efficiently store and manipulate sparse binary matrices in python?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

Binary matrix is a matrix which elements may be only 0 or 1.

I have a large (~40GB) sparse binary matrix in external database I can easily access. I want to compute a few first singular vectors for this matrix. Numpy arrays and scipy sparse formats are inefficient because they cannot store 1-bit values, they store at least 8bit integer.

In fact, I could store only indexes of non-zero elements, but in this case, I have to re-implement svd myself.

Is there a way to avoid this? Or I have to use some special cpp\fortran library for binary matrices?

Comment: what does this question have to do with c++?   removing tag.  Please don't re-add it unless you make a part of your question specific to c++

Comment: The same is true for Fortran...

Comment: @xaxxon sorry, I just added tags suggested by SO itself.

Comment: Try this http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html

Comment: @avstenit The problem is dtype is interger, but I can do with just one bit!

Comment: What kinds of manipulations are you doing?  What kinds of shapes (2d?, 1d).  How sparse?

Comment: @hpaulj it is adjacency matrix of the graph. I need to build graph Laplacian https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplacian_matrix and calculate a few smallest eigenvectors and second, I need to calculate a few larges svd vectors of original matrix and do several similar operations. Matrix in a size of a hundred millions million or so, with 1-2% fill in, may be even less.

Comment: AFAIK, most compilers implement booleans with 8bits now because it is just less efficient to have to place and extract multiple bits from a byte if a given operation only affects a single bit, which seems to be the case for you. That would be different for compression, but you want access. So I'd probably disagree with the broad characterization of numpy being inefficient for this case. It may use more memory, but it likely is faster than an implementation that contains multiple locations per byte.

Comment: @roadrunner66 yes, but in my case numpy memory inefficient and I cannot fit into the ram my problem